# Can the passive "to be amazed" be active?

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice, active-voice

I'm trying to find a way to write a sentence with active language where a character is amazed by something *without* making the something the subject of the sentence. For example:

> "Adam opened the door and was amazed to see Sarah."

Is there some way to craft this sentence where Adam *amazes* or something? Though, if Adam *amazes* then he's the one doing the amazing and Sarah would be amazed. I'm trying to find a way for Adam to be the one who is amazed, but with a different word that I can use in the active voice.

> "Adam opens the door and X to see Sarah,"

Where X is the word I'm looking for. Help!

Comment: Most expressions are passive, for the fairly obvious reason that the phenomenon *happens to Adam* - it's not something that he's actively doing. You could use *marvels*, but it's a little formal/dated/literary. Or *stares openmouthed*, for example, but that's not a single word.

Comment: "Adam opens the door and Sarah's presence amazes him"

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe such a structure exists in English. If Adam's the subject of the sentence, you need a passive construction to capture the effect of something else on him.

Comment: Per my comment, the (dated, if not actually archaic) verb *marvel* can be used in this way. But (again, per my comment) in general you're right.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

*gapes, goggles, drops his jaw, gawks, stops dead in his tracks,  boggles, staggers*.

Not all of them are exact drop-in replacesments for X, but they can all be active verbs:

> Adam opens the door and (gapes/goggles) to see Sarah.
>
> Adam opens the door and (drops his jaw/stops dead in his tracks/gawks/boggles/staggers) upon seeing Sarah standing there.

You could also tack on a few adjectives:

> Adam opens the door, only to stare slack-jawed at Sarah, who is standing there waiting with an air of impending doom hovering around her.

Comment: Could you expand a bit? For example, providing examples with the first two expressions you see as best for the OP's case.

Comment: Sure thing, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could always put Sarah in the lead.

> The sight of Sarah amazed Adam when he opened the door

Pretty odd way to phrase it though.